# How to detect when a NSPanel closes as a result of losing focus? E.g. A user clicking outside of the NSPanel (Window?)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow, nswindowcontroller, nspanel

I have a generic NSPanel window that I am using as a preferences window in my app. I have a selector that I call every time the window closes. The purpose of that selector is to save the state of the users chosen preferences (there is no "save" button).

I have an NSButton ("CLOSE") which I easily setup to call my closing selector.

I set it up so that my selector is also called when the user clicks the RED X in the top left corner of the NSPanel by doing:

```
NSButton *closeButton = [[self window] standardWindowButton:NSWindowCloseButton];
[closeButton setTarget:self];
[closeButton setAction:@selector(myCloseSelector:)];
```

This works perfectly. My problem though? The window **also** closes if the user clicks *outside* of the NSPanel. E.g. If they take their mouse and click on their browser window below the NSPanel that popped up. This also closes the window.

How do I catch my NSPanel losing focus and closing ? I need to ensure that when this happens I also get my selector called.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made my NSWindowController a delegate for NSWindowDelegate.

**myWindowController.h**

```
@interface myWindowController : NSWindowController <NSWindowDelegate>
```

and then set myWindowController as the delegate for my NSPanel.

Now I can implement:

```
- (void) windowDidResignKey:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"Houston...we lost a panel.");
}
```

and everything works swimmingly!